# Nokia Tile support in OL 3?

Tags: openlayers-3, here-api

In OL2, I am able to connect to Nokia tiles like this:

```
new OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ(
        "Nokia Road",
        [
                  "http://a.maptile.maps.svc.ovi.com/maptiler/maptile/newest/normal.day/${z}/${x}/${y}/256/png8?lg=ENG&app_id=...&token=..."
        ],
        {
            attribution: "&copy; 2013 Nokia</span>&nbsp;<a hre...",
            transitionEffect: "resize"
        }
    ),
```

I am wondering how to do this in OL3?

Comment: You should [edit] to split up your post into a question that details the problem you had and a (self-)answer that explains how you fixed it. Should be a useful combination, good work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can use the same token with HERE (Nokia) tiles:

```
var urlhere = 'http://{1-4}.base.maps.cit.api.here.com/'
    + 'maptile/2.1/maptile/newest/normal.day/'
    + '{z}/{x}/{y}/256/png8?app_id=...&app_code=...';
```

**UPDATE:**

It can also be:

```
var urlhere = 'http://{a-c}.maptile.maps.svc.ovi.com/maptiler'
    + '/v2/maptile/newest/normal.day/{z}/{x}/{y}/256/png8';
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. I am just realizing, now, we never changed the URL to the HERE domain.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

In OL3, I now do this:

```
new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.XYZ({
                url: "http://a.maptile.maps.svc.ovi.com/maptiler/maptile/newest/normal.day/{z}/{x}/{y}/256/png8?lg=...&token=...",
                attribution: new ol.Attribution({
                           html: '&copy; 2013 Nokia...'
                })
          })
});
```

Note: I needed to remove the **`$`** from the x, y, z values in the url.